# How to plot the value of abline in R?

Tags: r, plot

I used this code to make this plot:

```
plot(p, cv2,col=rgb(0,100,0,50,maxColorValue=255),pch=16, 
     panel.last=abline(h=67,v=1.89, lty=1,lwd=3))
```

My plot looks like this:
[image: Plot]

1.) How can I plot the value of the ablines in a simple plot?

2.) How can I scale my plot so that both lines appear in the middle?

Comment: by value of abline you mean? any example code at all?

Comment: no, I do not know what you mean by value of abline

Comment: Example code for generating the plot? An example (use paint if you need to!) of what you want?

Comment: That's my code: `plot(p, cv2,col=rgb(0,100,0,50,maxColorValue=255),pch=16, panel.last=abline(h=67,v=1.89, lty=1,lwd=3))` but I have no idea to print the value of the abline into the axis.

Comment: It should look like that: http://i.imgur.com/9Dd9d.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to change scale of plot so lines are in the middle change the axes i.e.

```
x<-1:10
y<-1:10
plot(x,y)
abline(a=1,b=0,v=1)

changed to:

x<-1:10
y<-1:10
plot(x,y,xlim=c(-30,30))
abline(a=1,b=0,v=1)
```

by "value" I am assuming you mean where the line cuts the x-axis?  Something like `text`? i.e.:

```
text((0), min(y), "number", pos=2)
```

if you want the label on the x axis then try:

```
abline(a=1,b=0,v=1)
axis(1, at=1,labels=1)
```

to prevent overlap  between labels you could remove the zero i.e.:

```
plot(x,y,xlim=c(-30,30),yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=c(1.77,5,10,15,20,25))
```

or before you plot extend the margins and add the labels further from the axis

```
par(mar = c(6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5))
plot(x,y,xlim=c(-30,30))
abline(a=1,b=0,v=1)
axis(2, at=1.77,labels=1.77,mgp = c(10, 2, 0))
```

Comment: This was my approach:

> plot(x, y, col=rgb(0,100,0,50,maxColorValue=255),pch=16, panel.last=abline(h=0.78,v=1.77, lty=1,lwd=3), yaxt = "n")
> 
> axis(2, las = 1) 
> axis(2, 0.78, 0.78, las = 1) 
> axis(1, 1.77, 1.77)

which leads to following image:

![Graphic](http://i.imgur.com/xdPkW.png)

You can see that 0.49 and 0 are overlapping... How can I solve this that they do not overlap?

Answer (score 0):

Similar in spirit to the answer proposed by @user1317221, here is my suggestion

```
# generate some fake points
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)

# positions of the lines
vert = 0.5
horiz = 1.3
```

To display the lines at the center of the plot, first compute the horizontal and vertical distances between the data points and the lines, then adjust the limits adequately.

```
# compute the limits, in order for the lines to be centered
# REM we add a small fraction (here 10%) to leave some empty space, 
# available to plot the values inside the frame (useful for one the solutions, see below)
xlim = vert + c(-1.1, 1.1) * max(abs(x-vert))
ylim = horiz + c(-1.1, 1.1) * max(abs(y-horiz))

# do the main plotting
plot(x, y, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
abline(h=horiz, v=vert)
```

Now, you could plot the 'values of the lines', either on the axes (the `line`parameter allows you to control for possible overlapping):

```
mtext(c(vert, horiz), side=c(1,2))
```

or alternatively within the plotting frame:

```
text(x=vert, y=ylim[1], labels=vert, adj=c(1.1,1), col='blue')
text(x=xlim[1], y=horiz, labels=horiz, adj=c(0.9,-0.1), col='blue')
```

HTH